# On shutdown, computer reboots when started via wake on lan

Tags: shutdown, reboot, wakeonlan

Here's the situation:

I start my main computer from another pc via wake on lan "wakeonlan ". All works fine. When I'm done doing what I did, I run "sudo shutdown -h now" (in the ssh terminal in which I was working) to shutdown the computer. But instead of shutting down, it reboots. I then have to reconnect to it via ssh and run the shutdown command again, and then it shuts down and stays off. I can then start it again via wake on lan...

does anyone know, why my computer actually reboots when I type "sudo shutdown -h now" when started via wake on lan?

Some information about the computer:

Ubuntu 13.04 
Moterboard: Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UD3H 
Ethernet Controller (as reported by "lspci"): Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)

Comment: patsee, I'm facing the same issue. Any solutions?

Comment: What (EFI?) BIOS version do you have? Others (including me) have reported the same issue with an Asus and GA-Z68X-UD3H-B3 board containing a Realtek card http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2013/06/msg01280.html

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the Asus P8H61-M LE/CSM with a Realtek Ethernet card.
Has anybody come up with some workaround for this? I read the debian email, but I also don't have Windows installed to test this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

There's one dirty solution

```
a) create /etc/init.d/reshutdown with the contents

#!/bin/sh
# force shutdown (due to bug in wakeonlan)
#


case "$1" in
reshutdown)
  touch /home/shutdown.chk
  shutdown -r now
;;

start)
 if [ -f /home/shutdown.chk ];
 then
    rm /home/shutdown.chk
    shutdown -h now
 fi
;;
esac

b) Execute: sudo chmod ugo+x /etc/init.d/reshutdown
b) Execute: sudo update-rc.d reshutdown start 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 .

c) Then to shutdown execute: sudo service reshutdown reshutdown
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, using the Intel DQ77MK motherboard, which has 2 onboard Intel GB ethers.
I fixed it by enabling the power bios entry "Native ACPI OS PCIe Support", which I guess allowed Ubuntu to reset the flag saying WOL has been triggered, probably with it disabled Ubuntu was not allowed by the BIOS to reset the flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately my bios does not have this option nor was I able to find a similar one. The problem still persists.

Answer (score -3):

Try `sudo poweroff`.

It works better with WOL for me.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I just tried to shutdown via "sudo poweroff" but unfortunately it is the same behavior as written in my op.

Comment: This is the same as `shutdown -h`, seriously.

Comment: @gertvdijk [`poweroff`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/poweroff.8.html) is not the same as `shutdown -h`, both because [`shutdown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/shutdown.8.html) takes a time argument and because `-h` means "halt or power off" rather than "power off." Rather, `poweroff` is similar to (and, except in runlevel 0 or 6, invokes) `shutdown -P now`.